# Xrandr shows HDMI1 disconnect w/ HDMI2 as primary with only one monitor

Tags: 16.04, drivers, intel-graphics, hdmi, xrandr

I'm unsure why the output of Xrandr is showing that HDMI1 as disconnected and HDMI2 as connected primary. There is only one monitor and one HDMI port in my current setup. As per the snippets below, I'm using the Intel HD graphics 500 chipset with the i915 driver. Is there something I'm missing here as to why HDMI1 is disconnected, or even why there is an HDMI2?

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 260mm x 140mm
   1280x720      60.00 +  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1360x768      59.95  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Contents of the monitors.xml file:

```
    <monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="HDMI1">
          <vendor>LSB</vendor>
          <product>0x0030</product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI2">
          <vendor>LSB</vendor>
          <product>0x0030</product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="VIRTUAL1">
      </output>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="HDMI-1">
          <vendor>LSB</vendor>
          <product>0x0030</product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI-2">
          <vendor>LSB</vendor>
          <product>0x0030</product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="HDMI1">
      </output>
      <output name="HDMI2">
          <vendor>LSB</vendor>
          <product>0x0030</product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="VIRTUAL1">
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Portion of the Xorg.0.log:

```
[    22.715] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    22.715] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    22.716] (EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
[    22.717] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:5a85:8086:2212 rev 11, Mem @ 0x90000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    22.717] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    22.718] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    22.735] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.735]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[    22.735]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    22.735] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    22.735] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    22.737] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.737]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 2.99.917
[    22.737]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.737]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    22.737] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    22.738] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    22.738] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    22.738] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    22.890] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20171023
[    22.890] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1~16.04.1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[    22.890] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    23.052] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 500
[    23.052] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2; using a maximum of 2 threads
[    23.052] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    23.052] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    23.052] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    23.052] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    23.053] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 using monitor section Configured Monitor
[    23.053] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    23.053] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[    23.053] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI2
[    23.053] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    23.054] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    23.054] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    23.054] (--) intel(0): Output HDMI2 using initial mode 1280x720 on pipe 0
[    23.054] (==) intel(0): TearFree enabled
[    23.054] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    23.054] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No cause for concern with extra HDMI monitor names

As long as everything works, you needn't worry how `xrandr` assigns monitor names.

In my setup for example:

```
$ xrandr | grep connected

HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
DP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+532 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Everything works and I'm not concerned there are duplicate names for HDMI-1 that show as "disconnected".

A better technique is to use:

```
$ xrandr | grep " connected "

HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1107mm x 623mm
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3840+2160 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
```

This technique spares you from sifting through "disconnected" monitors and more importantly is less confusing.